# No Authorization Header sending POST from Angular to Spring

Tags: spring, angular, cors

I have:

- a backend server written with **Spring**
- and a client written in **Angular**

I am trying to send a POST request...

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  login(username: string, password: string) {

    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Accept' : 'application/json',
        'Authorization' : 'Basic blablabla_base64_encoded'
      })
    };

    const body = 'username=' + username + '&password=' + password + '&grant_type=password';

    console.log(body);
    console.log(httpOptions.headers);
    console.log(this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:8080/oauth/token', body, httpOptions));

    return this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:8080/oauth/token', body, httpOptions)
      .map(
      user => {
        // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
        if (user && user.token) {
          // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
          localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
        }

        return user;
      });
  }

  logout() {
    // remove user from local storage to log user out
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
  }
}
```

Filtering the request with Wireshark I got:

```
OPTIONS /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:4200
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, 
like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.79 Safari/537.36
DNT: 1
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="oauth2/client"
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Allow: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sat, 09 Jun 2018 14:19:36 GMT
```

For some reason I have no Authorization header and my request from POST become OPTIONS. I searched for some hour other solutions over the web but none of them helped me.

Some advice?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to this question.

The Spring server has to manage also pre-flighted requests according to the paradigm explained in the documentation here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests

To add the CORS management is possible to add a CORSFilter before all other filters implemented in the Spring Boot App, with a good code example here:
https://gist.github.com/malike/f8a98b498368932e6d7511886a167848